# fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined in "jpeg_read"

Tags: matlab-compiler

I working on **"jpegtbx_1.4"**,But for compile **jpeg_read** gives the following `error: LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2008A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'jpeg_read.c' failed.` Who knows why this error occurs?